# Week and Strong Rolling Checksum

Tags: hash, synchronization, rsync, checksum

I'm doing a file sync application. for that I need to calculate both week and strong checksum for a file in client application and send it to the server. At the sever side, server needs to compare these checksum against a similar file (finding similar file is already implemented). I need week checksum to be 32 bit number and strong checksum to be 64 bit number. 
I got rSync source code but I couldn't figure it out how it works.
If anyone familiar with these algorithm, please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this: http://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/tech_report.html

It's pretty simple, and it is demonstrated in rsync's source code (see checksum.c).